# Проблема ввода и scanf

Tags: c, функции, ввод, printf, scanf

Столкнулся с проблемой: когда ввожу в ручную - программа работаем как и задумывалось, но стоит мне использовать `cat input | ./a` как программа откуда-то получает ***0 0***

Вот код программы: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/EUTshXxa) (смотрите функцию InputFiller)

P.S. Прошу не кидаться в меня тапками, сам пытался устранить проблему кучей разных способов... Как итог - заваленная лаба, а я пришёл сюда с последней надеждой.

P.P.S. Программа выполняет сортировку подсчетом

```
char InputFiller(struct token **token_dynmass) {

    //Нулевое место в массиве: макс индекс + кол-во элементов

    // Переменные
    unsigned short start_init = 4; // Кол-во инициируемых элементов по умолчанию
    float step_init = 1.5; // Кол-во эл-ов добавляемых в дин. массив за раз

    char tmp = 'i'; // Временная переменная (для тех. нужд)
    unsigned long long int qoe = 1; // Кол-во элементов в массиве  (0е место зарезервированно [см. выше])
    unsigned long long int freeqe = 0; // Кол-во элементов доступно

    // Инициализация структуры
    *token_dynmass = malloc(start_init * sizeof **token_dynmass);
    (*token_dynmass)[0].postindex = 0; //Обнуляем максимальный индекс

    // Непосредственное считывание данных
    freeqe = start_init - qoe;
        while (tmp != EOF) {
        // Выделение памяти
        if (freeqe == 0) {
            // Ограничитель на превышение кол-ва строк
            if ((qoe * (step_init - 1)) > ULLONG_MAX) {
                if ((qoe * (step_init - 1)) == ULLONG_MAX) {
                    return 65; // Если впихиваем невпихиваемое
                }
                else {
                    // Дополняем до предела
                    freeqe = ULLONG_MAX - qoe;
                }
            }
            else {
                // Нормальный прирост элементов
                freeqe = qoe * (step_init - 1);
            }

            // Расширяем массивчик структур
            *token_dynmass = realloc(*token_dynmass, qoe * step_init * sizeof **token_dynmass);

            // Исключение на случай нехватки памяти
            if (*token_dynmass == NULL) {
                return 63;
            }
        }

        // Считываем индекс (ключ)
        scanf("%u", &(*token_dynmass)[qoe].postindex);

        // Проверяем - является ли индекс максимальным?
        if ((*token_dynmass)[qoe].postindex > (*token_dynmass)[0].postindex)                     
        {
         (*token_dynmass)[0].postindex = (*token_dynmass)[qoe].postindex;
        }

        // Считываем данные (значение)
        scanf("%llu", &(*token_dynmass)[qoe].bedeutung);

        // Изменяем счетчики
        qoe++;
        freeqe--;

        // Cчитываем (\n или EOF)
        tmp = getchar();
    }

    // Укажем кол-во элементов
    (*token_dynmass)[0].bedeutung = qoe -1; //(т.к. нулевой - служебный)

    // Успех!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 0 0 как я понял она получает в конце

Comment: Добавьте код прямо в вопрос. См. [Справка: Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @insolor спасибо, добавил

Comment: Если последняя строка в файле заканчивается `\n`, то цикл не останавливается и "читает" следующую строку, которой нет. Не ясно, зачем вам вообще понадобилось отдельно считывать `\n`, если вы используете `scanf`.

Comment: @AnTтак мне нужно считывать, пока не будет EOF

Comment: Или scanf реагирует на EOF

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, классическая ошибка: `EOF` возникает только после неудачного чтения (в данном случае `scanf`'а), а корректный *текстовый файл* (по крайней мере в POSIX) всегда заканчивается переводом строки (который и читает `getchar()`). Правильно было бы организовать проверку на выход из цикла после ``scanf``'а, а также проверять, правильно ли от отработал.

Comment: @Fat-Zer и как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классическая ошибка: EOF возникает только после неудачного чтения (в данном случае scanf'а), а корректный текстовый файл (по крайней мере в POSIX) всегда заканчивается переводом строки (который и читает getchar()).

Правильно было бы организовать проверку на выход из цикла после scanf'а, а также проверять, правильно ли он отработал. Обычно цикл чтения выглядит как-то так:

```
  while (1) {
    unsigned key;
    long long unsigned val;
    int rc;

    rc = scanf ("%u %llu", key, val);
    if (rc == 2) {
      my_do_process_input(key, val);

      // ...

    } else if (rc == EOF) {
      if (!ferror(stdin)) {
          break;
      } else {
        fprintf (stderr, "Input error: %d (%s)", errno, strerror (errno));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    } else {
      fprintf (stderr, "Malformed input.");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
```