# Нестандартный выход из цикла С по EOF

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu

Есть код к задаче найти значения полинома в точке Х по схеме Горнера. Формат ввода данных из стандартного потока: х, an, an-1, an-2.... a1, a0.

Код к задаче:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

float x, a_i, result=0;
int c;
scanf("%f", &x);

while ((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
    scanf("%f", &a_i);
    result = a_i + result*x;
    
}
printf("\nResult: %g\n",result);
return 0;
```

Везде в литературе выход из цикла по признаку конца файла EOF оформляется в виде условия в цикле `while ((c=getchar())!=EOF)`. Но в моей системе Ubuntu 20.04 после компиляции `сс` при вводе данных через пробельную последовательность (пробел или перевод строки) после ввода последнего коэффициента А0, нужно дважды нажать (ctrl+d) чтобы цикл прервался и был выведен правильный результат. По идее нужно моментальное прерывание цикла с одним EOF. Прошу помочь разобраться с проблемой. Спасибо!

Проверочный ввод 1:

```
3 2 -6 2 -1
```

Проверочный ввод 2:

```
3
2
-6
2
-1
```

Вывод 5

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/900911/3380

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло. Все равно Ctrl+D приходится нажимать дважды

Comment: while (scanf("%f", &a_i) == 1)  - теперь ctrl+D + Enter.  А  Enter - потому что строку-то ввести надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш цикл `while ((c=getchar())!=EOF)` после перевода строки не останавливается, потому-что в буфере ещё остаётся этот символ и `getchar` его возвращает. При нажатии *Ctrl+D* буфер закрывается и дальнейшая команда `scanf("%f", &a_i);` возвращает *EOF* как код ошибки. Эту ошибку и нужно отлавливать:

```
int sc = scanf("%f", &a_i);
if ( sc == EOF ) 
  break ;
```

*Ещё может вернутся ноль, тогда буфер нужно очищать и попросить пользователя повторить правильно ввести число.*

Comment: Вставлял в условие while ( sc = scanf("%f", &a_i)!=EOF) - не помогает, нужно также дважды прожимать EOF

Comment: я проверял только с добавлением этой проверки и печатал сначала перевод строки, потом Ctrl+D - пашет. `getchar` - убирать не надо, он должен ентеры снять с буфера.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!

Comment: у меня проблемы такие бывают.. Ctrl+D работает **только** в **начале** строки.

Comment: Благодарю! Изучаю С только первый и последний семестр, о таких нюансах не догадывался.